ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : React.js API 400 bad request
I am working with an ASP.NET 8 Core Web API and React Framework and I am trying to test my API using Postman for sending data to database. After running the commands dotnet run for my backend app and npm start for the React frontend, I get this error:

This is my model file:
namespace PhotoAlbums.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
    }
}

And my controller file:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PhotoAlbums.Data;
using PhotoAlbums.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PhotoAlbums.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]

    public class AlbumsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public AlbumsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Album>> PostAlbum([FromBody] Album album)
        {
            _context.Albums.Add(album);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(PostAlbum), new { id = album.Id }, album);
        }       

        private bool AlbumExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Albums.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}

Also in my error is including the album field is required and I don't have column with name album in my table. Any help?

This endpoint can be tested using json (Body-raw-JSON) in postman. And you can reference the code on the right window to use in reactjs.

